# swift string advancedBy is slow?

Tags: swift

So I am writing in swift to practice some online judge.

Here's the issue: *Longest Palindromic Substring*

*Given a string S, find the longest palindromic substring in S. You may assume that the maximum length of S is 1000, and there exists one unique longest palindromic substring.*

So I am using dp to solve it in swift:

```
class Solution {
    func longestPalindrome(s: String) -> String {
        var hash = Array(count: s.characters.count, repeatedValue: Array(count: s.characters.count, repeatedValue: false))
        for i in 0 ..< s.characters.count {
            hash[i][i] = true
        }
        var maxStart = 0
        var maxEnd = 0
        var maxCount = 1
        for i in 1.stride(through: s.characters.count - 1, by: 1) {
            for j in 0 ..< s.characters.count - 1 {
                if j + i < s.characters.count {
                    if isValidPalindrome(j, j + i, s, hash) {
                        hash[j][j + i] = true
                        if maxCount < i + 1 {
                            maxCount = i
                            maxStart = j
                            maxEnd = j + i
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        // construct max palindrome string, swift string is so dummy
        var str = ""
        for i in maxStart...maxEnd {
            let index = s.characters.startIndex.advancedBy(i)
            str += String(s.characters[index])
        }
        return str
    }

    func isValidPalindrome(start: Int, _ end: Int, _ s: String, _ hash: [[Bool]]) -> Bool {
        // end <= s's length - 1
        let startIndex = s.startIndex.advancedBy(start)
        let endIdnex = s.startIndex.advancedBy(end)
        if end - start == 1 {
            return s[startIndex] == s[endIdnex]
        }
        else {
            let left = start + 1
            let right = end - 1
            return s[startIndex] == s[endIdnex] && hash[left][right]
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking it's a correct one, but when I submit, always time exceeded for long strings like:

```
"kyyrjtdplseovzwjkykrjwhxquwxsfsorjiumvxjhjmgeueafubtonhlerrgsgohfosqssmizcuqryqomsipovhhodpfyudtusjhonlqabhxfahfcjqxyckycstcqwxvicwkjeuboerkmjshfgiglceycmycadpnvoeaurqatesivajoqdilynbcihnidbizwkuaoegmytopzdmvvoewvhebqzskseeubnretjgnmyjwwgcooytfojeuzcuyhsznbcaiqpwcyusyyywqmmvqzvvceylnuwcbxybhqpvjumzomnabrjgcfaabqmiotlfojnyuolostmtacbwmwlqdfkbfikusuqtupdwdrjwqmuudbcvtpieiwteqbeyfyqejglmxofdjksqmzeugwvuniaxdrunyunnqpbnfbgqemvamaxuhjbyzqmhalrprhnindrkbopwbwsjeqrmyqipnqvjqzpjalqyfvaavyhytetllzupxjwozdfpmjhjlrnitnjgapzrakcqahaqetwllaaiadalmxgvpawqpgecojxfvcgxsbrldktufdrogkogbltcezflyctklpqrjymqzyzmtlssnavzcquytcskcnjzzrytsvawkavzboncxlhqfiofuohehaygxidxsofhmhzygklliovnwqbwwiiyarxtoihvjkdrzqsnmhdtdlpckuayhtfyirnhkrhbrwkdymjrjklonyggqnxhfvtkqxoicakzsxmgczpwhpkzcntkcwhkdkxvfnjbvjjoumczjyvdgkfukfuldolqnauvoyhoheoqvpwoisniv"
```

I can get the correct result `qahaq` after some time, and I am wondering why it's so slow. If I write it in other language, not so bad.

I suspect the API `s.startIndex.advancedBy(start)` is causing it, but I checked the doc, no time complexity and no other ways to turn an int to the startIndex type?

Any ideas to replace advancedBy? Thank in advance.

Comment: alright, I found one article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html, seems like swift string is much more complicated. Either I turn the string to an Array or NSString. I will try later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same issue: I turned swift String into Array, and it gets much faster.

I also looked into Swift source code about the advancedBy implementation, it's a O(n) opreation, that's why it's slow.

For whom is interested in the implementation, take a look at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8e12008d2b34a605f8766310f53d5668f3d50955/stdlib/public/core/Index.swift

You will see advancedBy is merely multiple successor():

```
  @warn_unused_result
  public func advanced(by n: Distance) -> Self {
    return self._advanceForward(n)
  }

 /// Do not use this method directly; call advanced(by: n) instead.
  @_transparent
  @warn_unused_result
  internal func _advanceForward(_ n: Distance) -> Self {
    _precondition(n >= 0,
        "Only BidirectionalIndex can be advanced by a negative amount")
    var p = self
    var i : Distance = 0
    while i != n {
      p._successorInPlace()
      i += 1
    }
    return p
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  Before implementing it, I recommend checking out some explanations such as this guy's.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obBdxeCx_Qs.  I'm not affiliated with him, though I do believe his video is somewhat useful.

```
  func longestPalindrome(_ s: String) -> String {
    var charArray = [Character("$"), Character("#")]
    for i in s.characters {
        charArray += [i, Character("#")]
    }
    charArray += [Character("@")]

    var mir = 0, c = 0, r = 0, longestPalindromeIndex = 0, longestPalindromeLength = 0, ss = "", returnString = ""
    var p = [Int]()

    //MARK: For loop
    for i in 0...(charArray.count - 1) {
        p += [0, 0]
        mir = 2 * c - i
        if i < r {
            p[i] = min(r - i, p[mir])
        }

        if i - (1 + p[i]) >= 0 && i + (1 + p[i]) < charArray.count - 1 {
            while charArray[i + (1 + p[i])] == charArray[i - (1 + p[i])] {
                p[i] += 1
            }
        }

        if p[i] > longestPalindromeLength {
            longestPalindromeIndex = i
            longestPalindromeLength = p[i]
        }

        if i + p[i] > r {
            c = i
            r = i + p[i]
        }
    }//for loop


    for i in Array(charArray[(longestPalindromeIndex - longestPalindromeLength)...(longestPalindromeIndex + longestPalindromeLength)]) {
        ss = String(i)
        if ss != "#" && ss != "$" && ss != "@" {
            returnString += ss
        }
    }
    return returnString
}//func
```